# Retrieving Available Product Filters in Spring Data Elasticsearch using API Client v8

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm working on a project using Spring Boot and Spring Data Elasticsearch, and I'm trying to implement a feature to retrieve a list of available product filters based on a search keyword. I have a Product schema that includes a nested field called filters, which consists of multiple Filter objects. Each Filter object has a filterName and a filterValue .

``    Product Schema:`

The Product schema defines a nested field called filters, which represents a list of filters associated with the product. Each filter has a filterName and a filterValue.

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
private List<Filter> filters;

@Data
public static class Filter {
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String filterName;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String filterValue;
}
```

```
Get Filters Logic:
```

The getFilters method performs a search in Elasticsearch based on the provided search keyword. It uses a fuzzy query to match the name field. Then, it defines two aggregations: termsSubAggregation to aggregate the filterValue field within the filters nested field, and termsAggregation to aggregate the filterName field. The aggregations are then added to the search request, and the response is returned.

```
public SearchResponse\<Product\> getFilters(String search) throws IOException {
Query query = FuzzyQuery.of(fQ -\> fQ
.field("name")
.value(search)
).\_toQuery();

    Aggregation termsSubAggregation = new Aggregation.Builder()
            .terms(builder -> builder
                    .field("filters.filterValue.keyword") // Update the field name to ".keyword"
                    .size(10)
            )
            .build();
    Aggregation termsAggregation = new Aggregation.Builder()
            .terms(builder -> builder
                    .field("filters.filterName.keyword") // Update the field name to ".keyword"
                    .size(10))
            .aggregations(new HashMap<>() {{
                put("values", termsSubAggregation);
            }})
            .build();
    Map<String, Aggregation> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Filter_Values", termsAggregation);
    
    SearchResponse<Product> response = elasticsearchClient.search(s -> s
            .query(query)
            .aggregations(map)
            , Product.class);
    
    List<Product.Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    
    System.out.println(response.aggregations().get("Filter_Values").toString());
    
    return response;

}
```

```
Kibana Query
```

The Kibana query is used to retrieve the desired filters based on the name field matching the provided "Apple" keyword. It uses nested aggregations to aggregate the filterName and filterValue fields within the filters nested field.

```
GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Apple"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "filterOptions": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "filters"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "availableOptions": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "filters.filterName",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filterValues": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "filters.filterValue",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
``
Result of Kibana Aggregations Query :

The aggregations provide the desired filter options based on the search keyword "Apple". The filterOptions aggregation contains buckets for each distinct filterName, and within each bucket, the filterValues aggregation contains buckets for each distinct filterValue corresponding to the filterName. The doc_count field represents the number of documents matching the specific filter.

{
  "aggregations": {
    "filterOptions": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "RAM",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "filterValues": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "16GB",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "color",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "filterValues": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Space Gray",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "processor",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "filterValues": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "Intel Core i7",
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}



I hope this provides enough context for the code sections. Please feel free to add any additional information or clarify your requirements when posting on Stack Overflow.
```